# Ubuntu 15.10 No interface, just the wallpaper

Tags: unity, 15.10, .desktop

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 and after login, i do have only the new wallpaper, I do only have that, no menus, no interface, nothing...

I see the login screen, once I log in, just the wallpaper. If i connect a USB the explorer opens and I can see all the folders, including the root.

Any suggestion?

**UPDATE:**

- I have tried to reinstall, reset, remove and install both Ubuntu-desktop and unity fully and no solutions.
- I have tried to activate the unity plugin. (was already activated).
- I have tried to reset the user files.
- tried to reinstall everything (.iso and OS).

None of those worked for me.

Comment: tried that post, but does not work...

Comment: "That post" has many different answers and solutions. Which ones did you try exactly?

Comment: all of them ;( the plugin is enabled. i have activated it and nothing. any other solution does not work.

Comment: If you log into another user account or the guest session, does Unity work there? Or create a new user from terminal with `sudo adduser --gecos "Test User" testuser` if you don't have one and try to log in that.

Comment: I cannot image that you tried all solutions from the the linked answers provided by @ByteCommander in this short time. Please follow the instructions given in my answer below, this solution solved the problem for many users who had the very same issue.

Comment: Not in that time, i found that post days ago. And i tested all of them before posting this question.

Comment: Does this happen in the guest session too?

Comment: yes, any user (guess, testuser, admin....)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue on my desktop computer, with Ubuntu 14.04
I found that problem is with the graphics incompatibility. **Are you using and graphics cards and any 3rd party graphics driver?**

Try to unplug it and then reinstall..if it will not work then try some other light weight desktop environment..**I presume your Xorg file is the main culprit**

Comment: yeah seems to be that, as all the solutions does not work, once I reach home i will check that.